# clean url with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I found several topics on mod_rewrite on stackoverflow but none them solved my problem. I also tried tutorial on this website http://edrackham.com/apache/beginners-mod_rewrite-tutorial/
I have been trying to use mod_rewrite to get clean url. For example:

```
  www.myweb.com/itemdetail.php?itemid=111234
```

to

```
  www.myweb.com/itemdetail/111234 or 
  www.myweb.com/itemdetail/iphone
```

This is my .htaccess file content.

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
   RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-l
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

As suggested in stackoverflow, I added following rewriterule to above file

```
   RewriteRule ^itemdetail/([0-9]+)/$ itemdetail.php?itemid=$1 [NC,L]
```

But this did not solve my problem. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the last slash optional :

```
RewriteRule ^itemdetail/([0-9]+)/?$ itemdetail.php?itemid=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: this did not fix the problem. any other suggestion.

Comment: where did you put it ? in the end of the htaccess ? if yes, it is normal that it didn't work because your other rule conflict with it, put it before it (right after the `RewriteEngine on`)

Answer (score 0):

On some servers you can't use a slash in a RewriteRule (I have the same problem). To check this try the following as your htaccess file:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^itemdetail-([0-9]+)/?$ itemdetail.php?itemid=$1
```

**EDIT:**
Of course your permalink would be www.myweb.com/itemdetail-111234

Comment: Try to search for 'mod_rewrite' in a phpinfo() output.